# GameTime and real time

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to fill a rectangle in 3 seconds of real time
I want the increment to be a constant value to look nice and not have acceleration 
and I am having trouble understanding what to do
this is my code

```
// constant
// 1.0f = 100% of rectangle, 3 sec = 3000.0 miliseconds
float addValue = 1.0f/3000.0f; 

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        newGameTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

        // once the percentage is set to 0 this starts
        if ((percentage < 1))
        {
            // calculate value here in order to time
            percentage += addValue;
        }
    }
```

I've been trying all kind of crazy math to get it right but i completely lost it. :(
I know I should be using gameTime or newGameTime but I'm lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume thats your update / rendering function.

Let's say, for example, that since the last rendering, 300ms elapsed. That means you'd have to add 100%/3000ms * 300ms = 10% to your rectangle.

-> You're missing the elapsed time in the calculation:

```
percentage += addValue * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
```

Comment: From what i can gather from the question i think he wants the rectangle to fill in 3 "solid" steps, instead of a regular progress bar. At least that's what I think he intends to do.

Comment: He asked to fill it in 3 "realtime seconds". I would assume the rate the Update function gets called at is FPS-dependant so he has to take the time passed since the last update and use that to calculate the progress.

Comment: It depends on whether you're using FixedTimeStep or not. Either way using the time is not a bad idea; FixedTime simply makes sure that time value is consistent.

Comment: can't I use the newGameTime increment to make those calculations? After i added the elepsedTime to the addvalue the bar just fills too fast and it doesn't take 3 seconds more like 3 miliseconds <br/> -edit- <br/> ok I checked again and seems I was seting the wrong addValue in another class... finally seems to be working fine now. <br/>Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely wrong with this answer according to what ccKep just mentioned in his comment.

But just in case it's what you're looking for, I put this together.

The main idea is having a timer event controling the increment. Even if the code I'm submitting isn't appropriate, maybe the idea will apply.

```
    public int percentage;
    public int Percentage
    {
        get { return percentage; }
        set
        {
            percentage = value;
            if (Percentage >= 0 && Percentage < 100)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Percentage = 0;
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Percentage = 0;
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double addValue = 100 / 3;
        Percentage += (int)addValue;
    }
```